# Systemd is not working it changed to init

Tags: google-compute-engine, systemd, init

My VM debian 10, on google cloud simply changed, after a reboot, from systemd to init. None of systemctl command is working with the error message:
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is off

Comment: You cannot easily recover the VM with this problem. Solution: Detach the persistent disk or create a disk copy from a snapshot, create a new Debian 10 VM, attach the disk and extract valuable data.

Comment: Thanks man. I have an snapshot days before, and other ways to solve this but what i really want to know is what causes this (i know, too much to ask)... or a simple command to switch from init to systemd again